# How to get a value from block configuration's form control?

Tags: 7, blocks

I'm new to drupal stackexchange and drupal too.

I have made an example module that creates a block called "example". I added a textfield form control to the "example" block's configuration page using the `hook_block_configuration` hook function. Now I'm trying to get the value from the block configuration's form control in my `hook_block_view` hook function.

Here is what I have so far:

```
function example_block_info() {

    $blocks = array();

    $blocks['example'] = array(
        'info' => t('example'),
    );

    return $blocks;

}// end function

function example_block_configuration($delta = '') {

    $form = array();

    switch($delta) {

        case 'example' :

        $form['text'] = array(
          '#type' => 'textfield',
          '#title' => t('Text'),
          '#default_value' => '',
          '#size' => 50,
          '#maxlength' => 100,
          '#required' => true,
        );

    }// end function

    return $form;

}// end function

function example_block_view($delta) {

    $block = array();

    switch($delta) {

        case 'example' :
            $block['content'] = get_block_content(),
            break;

    }// end switch

    return $block;


}// end function

function get_block_content() {

    return /* textfield form control value */

}// end function
```

I figured I have to use the `hook_block_save` hook function to get the value from the '$edit' argument and store it somehow, but I'm not show how, or if that's the correct way to go about it.

```
function example_block_save($delta = '', $edit = array()) {

    switch($delta) {

        case 'example' :

            $edit['text'];

            break;

    }// end switch

}// end function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is completely covered in example module: [block_example.module](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/block_example!block_example.module/7)

Have a look at following hooks:

1. block_example_block_configure
2. block_example_block_save
3. block_example_block_view

Comment: Can you give an example using my example code?

Comment: Oh wait, nevermind, I get it, I have to use `variable_set()` in my `hook_block_save()` hook function, and `variable_get()` in my `hook_block_view()` hook function. Thanks, I mark your answer as correct and I'll update my question to show the solution later. Thanks.